# Align card to both ends with one css class?

Tags: html, css

I am not really HTML/CSS guy so excuse me if it's something really simple. I've some code that produces this.

[image]

Here is a relevant part of CSS

```
div.content {
    /* padding: 4px 0px 5px 11px; */
    /* margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; */
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    overflow: hidden; /* NEW */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    align-self: auto;
}


div.column {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    /*  width: 100%; */
    float: left;
}
div.twol {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% / 2 - 20px);
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
div.twor {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% / 2 - 20px);
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
}
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Originally I was using only `div.two` with `float:left` but whatever I tried it would keep both of top charts aligned to the left making the uneven alignment. Is there a way to get those charts (within cards) to always align so that it's kind of justified? The goal is that when it's one column it goes from edge to edge and I would like to keep it similar when it comes to two, three and so on columns. I don't want to create multiple CSS to cover each and every scenario there is.

Here is the old approach with one `div.two`. Notice how top charts are not aligned to left/right making the overall size of 1st row smaller than a 2nd row.
[image]

The solution should work for 1,2,3,4,5,6 "columns" (not sure if that matters).

Just in case you need full html: https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML/blob/master/Examples/Example9/Example9.html

Comment: Do you refer to the space between the cards in the middle? If not could you try highlighting it in your images?

Comment: if you compare 1st and 2nd picture there is space on the right side. Space should be minimal, similar to the one on the left. In other words left image should be aligned to left, the right image to right. if possible space between images should be similar to the one on the left and right with assumption similar thing happening if there is 3, 4, 5 or more columns.

Comment: Got it know. Are you using Bootstrap 4 or any CSS framework? If so could you provide the HTML so that I give you the most suitable solution?

Comment: Added html link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is due to `box-sizing` property, which is currently set to `border-box`. This makes the `padding` applied to the element be subtracted from its width, so you will not have to consider this in the `width` of the elements.

As you have the following ruleset (excerpt):

```
div.two {
    width: calc(100% / 2 - 20px);
    padding: 10px;
}

.card {
   margin: 5px;
}
```

What this actually does is that it sets the width of the cards to half of the parent's size minus 20px (which would be the padding as you would have thought), but as you have `box-sizing: border-box`, the padding is already taken care of, but you still have 10px total margin for each card yet subtract 20px in the formula.

So the solution would simply be:

```
div.two {
    width: calc(100% / 2 - 10px);
    padding: 10px;
}

div.column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This way the cards will take the full width overall and still have the spacing in between them.

This solution will work with any number of columns – you would only have to divide the width by the number of columns (e.g. for 4 columns: `calc(100% / 4 - 10px)`).

Learn more about [`box-sizing`](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) property at CSS-Tricks.

---

Also just as an aside, in the linked HTML you seem to have two `<html>` tags. You should have only one for [conforming with the standards](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Comment: Thanks for HTML tip. Was error on PowerShell generating this. Well change div.two to your solution doesn't solve my problem. If I do like you said. I've updated html code so you can see. The output is that 1st row splits into 2 rows.

Comment: You're welcome @MadBoy. Have just looked at the updated example, now it seems the `box-sizing` property is not there anymore. Best to specify it as `div.column {box-sizing: border-box;}`, and as explained in the answer you would need to subtract `10px` from the width to account for both sizes of the margin (5 on each side): `width: calc(100% / 2 - 10px)`.

Comment: doesn't work like that. Updated like you said and it's just split into two rows.

Comment: You would still need the `float: left` @MadBoy, I did not mention removing it or the margin of 5px.

Comment: If I leave float:left the marging is on the right and it's not what I want :/

Comment: Do you want to have the same small margin as on the left or completely disappear? If you apply the ruleset I specified in the answer and keep the other styling as before (i.e. margin of 5px and float left) the excessive margin will disappear. I have tested this both times so that's really the problem. Let me know if you can't get it fixed and I will send you the updated HTML.

Comment: Well whatever it doesn't keep margins visually the same on the left and right side. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: [Here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/m7d8hou6/) @MadBoy. Just reapplied the float and margin on your latest code.

Comment: That works! I've modified my PowerShell code to generate it for all columns this way. Seems to work properly. Thank you, a lot. I was ready to switch to flex-grid or css-grid (I still may do that) but this solves it for me now!

Comment: The only advantage of `float` for grid-based design is browser support (supported in virtually all browsers). Would browsers like IE9 not matter to you, it would be a good idea to switch to grid or flexbox when you get the time. Also, you could mark the answer as correct so that other people browsing through know the solution has worked.

Comment: I don't need IE9 support. Chrome/Firefox/Edge should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Flexbox, it makes life way easier. Here's an simple example:

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  background: teal;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 1%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col">Column 3</div>
  <div class="col">Column 4</div>
  <div class="col">Column 5</div>
  <div class="col">Column 6</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col">Column 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess Flex-grid or css grid layout would be the way to go if everything else fails.

Comment: how would I resize it ? So that when I start shrinking it goes down from 6 columns to 5, 4 and finally 1?

Comment: @MadBoy well, Flexbox is integrated by default into CSS so you should be using that instead of float as floats can get very messy (think of Flexbox as the future of floats). It resizes based on the width of the body (in my example, the flexbox is sized based on the width of the `.flex-grid` div.)

Comment: @MadBoy you should add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.flex-grid` to make them automatically shrink and put them into more columns.